# How to show items data by jQuery roundSlider plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to show Price data from db by jQuery roundSlider.

There is a simple model

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Controller, where two methods Index and Details where I get item with price and have to show at view by roundSlider.

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    private ItemsContext db = new ItemsContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = db.Items.ToList();
        return View(items);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        var itemPrice = db.Items.Where(i => i.Id == id).Select(p => p.Price);
        if (itemPrice == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        return View(itemPrice);
    }
}
```

View: Details

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.css">
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/CustomScripts/SliderJs.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4 id="ddd">Item</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Script SliderJs of roundSlider

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#slider").roundSlider({
    radius: 90,
    width: 10,
    handleSize: "+10",
    sliderType: "range",
    value: "0,100"
});
```

There is an image of view Details [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Wxa.png)

And roundSlider have to show the price value for example 41.

I supposse that there is I should add something like this, but it is not correct.

```
$.get({
    url: /Items /Details/l,
    data: { price: price}
})
```

I`m looking for advices, how to show price by slider. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the price of the current item your detail view is rendering, you can read the Price property value of the current page mdoel and pass that to the value property of the settings object.

This will work in your razor view.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#slider").roundSlider({
            radius: 90,
            width: 10,
            handleSize: "+10",
            sliderType: "range",
            value: @Model.Price
        });

    });

</script>
```

Since your js code to enable the plugin is inside an external js file, you should read the `Model.Price` value in your razor view and pass it to the the js file

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        var myApp= myApp|| {};            
        myApp.itemPrice = @Model.StateId;
    </script>
    <script src="~/CustomScripts/SliderJs.js"></script>
}
```

Now in your `SliderJs.js`, you can read the value of `myApp.itemPrice` and use that to set the initial value of the slider

```
(function ($, window, myApp) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#slider").roundSlider({
            radius: 90,
            width: 10,
            handleSize: "+10",
            sliderType: "range",
            value: myApp.itemPrice
        });

    });
})(jQuery, window, myApp);
```

Comment: thank you it is working. Can you suggest, if I want by slider to chande price data and save it at data base, should I use ajax or it can be simle jQuery function?

Comment: You can do an ajax post to update the data or use jquery to update the DOM element value (of your form input element) and do a normal form posting. It is totally up to you how you want to do it.